# Java Swing decorated JFrame with rounded corners

Tags: java, swing, windows-10, jframe, awt

I'm looking for a way to create a JFrame with rounded corners AND also have the close and minimize buttons in the right to corner of the frame.
Is there asimple solution since the following only adds rounded corners with setUndecorated(true):

```
setUndecorated(false);
addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
        setShape(new RoundRectangle2D.Double(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), 20, 20));
    }
});
```

I know in Windows 11 the frames would automatically have rounded corners but I need a solution for Windows 10.

Comment: Because the frame decorations are provided by the native OS, it's not possible (always) possible to have a custom frame shape on a decorated window (while using the native look and feel)

Comment: Looking at the source code for `Frame#setShape`, `if ((shape != null) && !isUndecorated()) {` it's actually hardcode to be impossible

Comment: It "might" possible if you used the JNA library (I've not tried), but it's API has something which might work - [`WindowUtils.setWindowMask(Component, Shape)`](https://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.1/com/sun/jna/platform/WindowUtils.NativeWindowUtils.html#setWindowMask-java.awt.Component-java.awt.Shape-)

Comment: So I tried JNA and on MacOS, it still doesn’t like it when it’s decorated

Comment: Too bad. Maybe adding a new component with the functionality of the menu bar (minimize, close and if needed dragging) to the undecorated shaped frame will be the most simple option.

Comment: You could use a Look & Feel decorated Window for that, but unfortunately, the Windows Look & Feel does not support this feature. It does support internal frames though, which you could add to a shaped window, but they get an outdated ugly look instead of Windows 10’s native look.